# what is a Network Architecture

Tags: design, network-core, architecture

what is the exact difference between network architecture and network design?
can I call the whole company network design as a network architecture.?
why network architecture needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to think of a network architecture as spelling out what it is you want to achieve with the network (linking together discrete areas of functionality/locations in a business) - and is written in a way that a non-technical person can understand it.  It will talk more about functionality (connect to AWS, fail-over between data centres, security zones etc) than necessarily how this functionality will be achieved.

On the other hand, a network design is more the nuts and bolts you will use to make the architecture happen (specific devices you use, routing protocol configuration, firewall rules etc.) and is targeted at a technical audience.  I tend to work on the principle that the network design should contain enough detail that a Network Engineer should be able to take the design and build the complete network from just your document.

As for the purpose of the architecture, it's to capture the business requirements of the network without going into detail as to exactly how they are going to be achieved.

I like the phrase "Architecture is about doing the right things, Design is about doing things right"

Comment: This is a very opinionated topic. I think the two terms are interchangeable.

Comment: I want to clarify that the architecture means goals & functionalities whereas design means like designing the topology and selecting the devices and media cables am i correct?

Comment: Yes - that's pretty much my view.

Answer (score 0):

[Engineer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineer) and [architect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architect) are well established titles with accompanying testing, recognition, and requirements.  These titles often have special legal protections.  It is unfortunate that the I.T. industry has co-opted these titles.

Regarding network architecture and network design, you will not find an authoritative and recognized differentiation.  They mean the same thing.  Since network design does not infringe upon the architecture industry, I prefer to use the term network design.

That's my 2 cents...